# Dart passing generic Function<T>(T t) seems to require cast, all other ways signatures don't match

Tags: dart

With the below code as an example I can not figure out how to make the generic typed Function work with out casting as shown. Every other way I try I get some variation of

> The argument type 'Null Function(Gift)' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'dynamic Function(T)'

```
var present = Present<Gift>(Gift('Fancy Gift'), <T>(Gift t) {
    print('${(t as Gift).name} was opened.');
  });
```

or

> The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

```
var present = Present<Gift>(Gift('Fancy Gift'), <Gift>(t) {
    print('${t.name} was opened.');
  });
```

Here is the working example with a cast.

```
void main() {
   var present = Present<Gift>(Gift('Fancy Gift'), <T>(t) {
    print('${(t as Gift).name} was opened.');
  });
  present.open();
}


class Present<T> {
  final T _item;
  final Function<T>(T t) openedCallback;

  T open() {
    openedCallback.call(_item);
    return _item;
  }

  Present(this._item, this.openedCallback);
}

class Gift {
  final String name;

  Gift(this.name);
}
```

There should be a way to do this without a cast right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class definition does not do what you intend:

```dart
class Present<T> {
  final T _item;
  final Function<T>(T t) openedCallback;
  ...
```

`openedCallback` is separately parameterized; its `T` type parameter is separate and independent from that of `Present<T>`.  There is no need to parameterize `openedCallback` since you presumably want:

```dart
class Present<T> {
  final T _item;
  final Function(T t) openedCallback;
  ...
```

After that, you can do:

```dart
  var present = Present<Gift>(Gift('Fancy Gift'), (t) {
    print('${t.name} was opened.');
  });
```

Note that doing `<T>(t) { ... }` or `<Gift>(t) { ... }` is counterproductive.  That declares an anonymous function that itself is generic and is has a type parameter named `T` or `Gift` respectively.